# Execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, telerik, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC web application, working with Entity Framework Core 5.

We implement web components, like Grid or Spreadsheet (we work with Telerik). When I do some changes in the component, and then try to save the changes, the component calls my `ApplicationDbContext.SaveChanges`. And then I get the following error:

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: The configured execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated transactions. Use the execution strategy returned by 'DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy()' to execute all the operations in the transaction as a retriable unit.

[image]

Here is my method where I `ConfigureServices` for the DBContext:

```
public static void AddDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
            providerOptions =>
            {
                providerOptions
                    .EnableRetryOnFailure(
                        maxRetryCount: 5, 
                        maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                        errorNumbersToAdd: null)
                    .UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
            });
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        options.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning));
    });
```

That error does not happen systematically. For sure when I try to save to DB multiple elements. But also when only one element. Does not happen when I edit or same an element one by one, in a classic form, only when it happens in multiple objects scenario (Grid or Spreadsheet)...

The StackTrace would be like this:
[image]

As example, I give bellow a method allowing to submit `Entreprise` objects, from a Spreadsheet to the DB, in order to use `CreateExecutionStrategy` method:

```
public ActionResult Data_Source_Entreprises_Submit(SpreadsheetSubmitViewModel model)
{
    var result = new SpreadsheetSubmitViewModel()
    {
        Created = new List<SpreadsheetEntrepriseViewModel>(),
        Updated = new List<SpreadsheetEntrepriseViewModel>(),
        Destroyed = new List<SpreadsheetEntrepriseViewModel>()
    };

    if ((model.Created != null || model.Updated != null || model.Destroyed != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /*             executionStrategy                                 */
        var executionStrategy = _dbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

        executionStrategy.Execute(() =>
            {
                using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ///////// Business Logic //////////////////
                        if (model.Created != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var created in model.Created)
                            {
                                EntrepriseDTO dto = new EntrepriseDTO() { Nom = created.Nom };
                                var createdDto = _entrepriseService.Create(dto);
                                created.Id = createdDto.Id;
                                result.Created.Add(created);
                            }
                        }

                        if (model.Updated != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var updated in model.Updated)
                            {
                                var spec = new EntrepriseForDetailsSpecification(updated.Id);
                                var dto = _entrepriseService.Read(spec);
                                dto.Nom = updated.Nom;
                                _entrepriseService.Update(dto);
                                result.Updated.Add(updated);
                            }
                        }

                        if (model.Destroyed != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var destroyed in model.Destroyed)
                            {
                                _entrepriseService.Delete(destroyed.Id);
                                result.Destroyed.Add(destroyed);
                            }
                        }
                        ///////// END Business Logic ///////////////

                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
        /*             END executionStrategy                   */
        
        return Json(result);
    }
    else
    {
        return StatusCode(400, "The models contain invalid property values.");
    }
}
```

as result I had the following error:

> The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets

Then I modified the connection string, including `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`, but finally obtained another error:

> A second operation was started on this context before a previous
> operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads
> concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more
> information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

I don't use in that code asynchronous code, I don't know what is wrong...

Answer (score 14):

I needed to verify all my repository Async calls, and see if all of them was "awaited".

I found one that was not "awaited"... fixing that permitted me to save the objects from the Grid(or Spreadsheet) in the DB. More information is in the MS docs on [EF Core Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async)...